# how to destroy session with ajax when input blank,Error Undefined variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Notice: Undefined variable: outputname**

I have a query in `memberSearch.php` file. So I want to do `echo $outputname variable` in another `PHP file` in the `input tag`.

So after echo this `($outputname )` in another file its returning error `Undefined variable`.

- `I tried with adding null variable ($outputname = ""; ) but then result not appears.`
- `I also included (memberSearch.php) file but problem not solved.`
- `I saved this variable in session So by session problem resolved but got another problem .means I am doing echo that session in the input tag. SO problem is I am using Ajax for autocomplete input tag.`

so if I use session in input tag then it's not gonna destroy .

please help
thanks

This is `memberSearch.php` file code:-

```
       <?php include "header.php"; ?>
    <?php include "/includes/db.php" ?>
    <?php include "/includes/functions.php" ?>


       <?php

    if(isset($_POST["query"]))
    {

        $output = '';
        $outputname ='';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM add_members WHERE member_id LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $outputid .= $row["member_id"];
                $outputname .= $row["member_name"];
                $outputdate .= $row["member_date"];
            }



        }

  $response = array(
         'outputid'     => $outputid, 
         'outputname'   => $outputname, 
         'outputdate'   =>  $outputdate
);


}


        ?>
```

This is addBankAccount.php file code:-

```
<!--=======================  including header.php File  ============================-->
<?php include "header.php"; ?>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">

<!--=======================  including sidebar.php File  ============================-->
      <?php include "sidebar.php"; ?>



<!--=======================  including navigation.php File  ============================-->
      <?php include "navigation.php"; ?>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  

        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">
          <div class="">
            <div class="page-title">
              <div class="title_left">
                <h3>Add Bank Account</h3>
              </div>

              <div class="title_right">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Add Bank Account <small>Fill This Information Carefully</small></h2>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <br />
                    <form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="memeber-id">Enter Member Id <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" id="member_idd" name="member_idd" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                        </div>
                        <div id="memberID"></div>

                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#member_idd').keyup(function(){
                                var query = $(this).val();

                            if(query != '')
                            {
                                 $.ajax({
                            url:"memberSearch.php",
                            method:"POST",
                            data:{query:query},
                            data:outputid,
                            data:outputname,
                            data:outputdate,         
                            success:function(data)
                            {
                                  $('#memberID').fadeIn();
                                  $('#memberID').html(data);


                            }

                            });
                            }

                            });

                                   $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
                                   $('#member_idd').val($(this).text());  
                                   $('#memberID').fadeOut();  
                             });  
                             });  
                  </script>


                       </div>


                  <?php include "memberSearch.php"; ?>      


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Member Name 
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                        <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" value="<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" disabled="disabled">

                    </div>
                  </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Bank Account Number</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input id="middle-name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="middle-name" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">AccountType<span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <select id="heard" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Choose..</option>
                            <option value="press">Press</option>
                            <option value="net">Internet</option>
                            <option value="mouth">Word of mouth</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Amount<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input id="middle-name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="middle-name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input id="middle-name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="middle-name" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-5">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Account</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->



<!--=======================  including footer.php File  ============================-->
      <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

[image: please see the image]

I am getting error Notice: Undefined variable: response in

Comment: You really need to show us some code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I uploaded the code.Please check

Comment: Your `php` is not correct. You are echoing the variables two times and this will not work. You need to put those vars in an array, then use echo json_encode($your_array).

Comment: You aren't escaping your user inputs, which makes you wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.

Comment: @Franco can you please check the code once again. I added the variables in array (memberSearch.php) Line number 29 to 31.

and did echo in (AddBankAccount.php) .see code line number 61 to 107. 

Please help me to correct it.
Thanks

Comment: @Gurjitsingh If you do it with ajax, you need to "session_start();" again in the PHP file, which is called via AJAX and afterwards you can destrox the session.

Comment: @BlackOps Yes, I know it's easy to get value by using session in PHP. But the problem is I don't know how can I start a session and destroy session in ajax. Because every time changes the Member ID in  input field then old session should destroy by ajax. can you help me to do this or send me examples please?

Answer (score 0):

I can not put this in the comments so I will put this in here:

You need to pass the array like this:

```
$response = array(
         'outputid'     => $outputid, 
         'outputname'   => $outputname, 
         'outputdate'   =>  $outputdate
);
```

Then you need to echo the result in order to pass the response to the ajax call:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Subsequently in your returned success response you can address the variables:

```
data.outputid
data.outputname
data.outputdate
```

Comment: I am not good in ajax i know only PHP. Can you please send me the correct code .Then i can understand. Please see my code again i changed as per your suggestion and correct it please.